# Genlocking 5-6 sj4000

Tags: video, 360video

I'm planning on buying 5-6 sj4000 and use them to create 360 images and videos. This is the oem sj400, not sjcam sj4000. Does anyone have an idea how to genlock to trigger them together. I've seen many options to genlock gopros but not sj4000.

Link: http://www.ebay.com/itm/1080P-SJ4000-Waterproof-DVR-Sports-DV-HD-Video-Action-Camera-Camcorder-Car-Cam-/141732463492?hash=item20ffe9c384

Comment: isn't genlocking unique to video?

Comment: You say images and videos, but if this is primarily a video technique, you'll have better luck on video.stackexchange